# Oracle stored procedure with parameter

Tags: sql, string, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am fairly new to Oracle SQL. I am trying to create a stored procedure which takes 2 parameters. I am getting errors when I save below. Any idea ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SWAP_VIEWS 
(
  SchemaName NVARCHAR,
  TableName NVARCHAR
) AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE SQLstring NVARCHAR :=
      'ALTER VIEW  AS POL.V_' + TableName + ' as SELECT * FROM ' + SchemaName + '.' + TableName
  EXEC SQLstring;
END SWAP_VIEWS ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be mixing SQL Server and Oracle syntax here:

- Oracle uses standard operator `||` for string concatenation, not `+`
- Oracle wants `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` instead of `EXEC`
- you need `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`
- `NVARCHAR2` should be preferred to `NVARCHAR`

Note that you don't need an intermediate variable assignment, you can concatenate the query string and execute it at once.

Consider:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SWAP_VIEWS (
  pSchemaName NVARCHAR2,
  pTableName  NVARCHAR2
) AS 
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  AS POL.V_' 
    || pTableName + ' as SELECT * FROM ' 
    || pSchemaName || '.' || pTableName;
END;
/
```

Comment: I am getting the following errors in compiling code:                                                           
Error: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Error(3,14): PLS-00201: identifier 'NVARCHAR' must be declared

Comment: Try using 'NVARCHAR2'.

Comment: @AndyDan: thank you, indeed this seems to work now: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ad514c02247157b769e1586d3300f093

Answer (score 2):

Here the version corrected

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SWAP_VIEWS 
(
  SchemaName NVARCHAR,
  TableName NVARCHAR
) AS 
SQLstring varchar2(4000);
BEGIN

 SQLstring := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW POL.V_' || TableName || ' as SELECT * FROM ' || SchemaName || '.' || TableName ' ;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLstring;
  
END SWAP_VIEWS ;
/
```

- The concatenation character is |
- The variable SQLString must be declared
- The way to execute a variable is EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
- You can use CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW instead of ALTER VIEW

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your procedure and modified like below, see if it works. Additionally i want to say, you can explicitly do exception handling in the procedure to capture any error during the execution and also creating view with '*' has some disadvantages. Please chek

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SWAP_VIEWS 
(
  p_schema_name IN NVARCHAR2,
  p_table_name  IN NVARCHAR2
)
IS
    lo_sql_string NVARCHAR2(4000);
    lo_view_name NVARCHAR2(30);
    lo_table_name NVARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
    -- I just prefer local variables for convenience to avoid more complex string in actual one and also for debugging purpose
    lo_view_name := 'POL.V_'||p_table_name;
    lo_table_name := p_schema_name||'.'||p_table_name;
    lo_sql_string:= 'create or replace view '||lo_view_name||
                               ' as '||
                               'select * from '||lo_table_name;
  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lo_sql_string;
END SWAP_VIEWS;
/
```